# Help with understanding transistors in circuits

Tags: amplifier, sound

[image]

The picture above is a circuit for a hearing aid, so we need sound amplification.
BC547 is NPN, BC557 is PNP. How is the amplification happening, why is it connected so?

Edit: I found a circuit for sziklai pair amplification.

[image]

Looking at my original yellow circuit I can't understand why the rightmost BC547 is connected as it is. I see that the output is obtained from the emitters of the pair in sziklai pair ckt. Why is the BC547(rightmost) added to emitters of the sziklai pair and just inserted in between?

Comment: There are no Sziklai pairs in your circuit. The 10k resistor biases the electret microphone.

Comment: I may be wrong here, from what I read the first two transistors are joined like in sziklai

Comment: You are wrong or what you read was wrong.

Comment: Do you know what transistor config is this?

Comment: There are as many transistor configurations as you and I have had hot dinners and most of them are unnamed. Knowing the name of something doesn't make it easier to solve I'll also add.

Comment: edited it. My bad.

Comment: Where did you find the schematic - it's a really poor design and could cause acoustic shock as far as I can see.

Comment: It's meant to be a lower level project, I just want to get a rough idea of how amplification is happening. My friend gave me this schematic, said was involving darlington pairs. He can't explain it too most probably.

Comment: Sorry, but there are too many imperfections in the design to make it suitable for analysis. Maybe wait for someone else.

Comment: The horrible circuit is from www.talkingelectroinics.com in Australia. There are much better but more complicated hearing aid circuits there. My hearing aids produce the high frequency boost needed by my normal-for-my-age hearing loss but these simple circuits do not.

Answer (score 1):

Given this circuit HAS ONLY 1,500 milliVolts to work with, this is an implementation that deserves some understanding.

The 3 transistors implement a super_beta amplifier.

There is very little Miller Effect, so the frequency response does not suffer.

Notice the voltage divider that sets the bias: 220K to rail, 330K to ground.
Thus, ignoring base current (which gets bootstrapped anyway, thru the 10Kohm DC feedback), the Vbase is 60% of 1.5v, or 0.9 volts.

Given Lo collector current thru first transistor, assume 0.5 volts Vbe, thus need a total of 0.4 volts across 10K ohm (which is 100 microAmps per volt) and that 3.3 ohm ouput emitter resistor. Most of the 0.4 volts will be across the 3.3 ohms, thus 30 milliAmps Icollector of the 3rd transistor, as first pass bias thinking.

However --- these 3 transistors have very low Vce, thus beta **MAY** be defined by the shape of the I_V curve where the Early Effect (the flattening) has not kicked in.

If we assume a beta of 5 !!! for each transistor, then we need substantial current thru the 10Kohm, to support that large current thru the 3.3 ohm.

Interesting design, to function well on 1.5 volts, with very few components.

Comment: The horrible circuit puts its class-A high output current into the earpiece forcing its cone to one side causing no sound or severe distortion and killing its battery very quickly.

Comment: I've also edited my question.

Comment: Can it be called a sziklai pair? and what will be the output amplification? for a normal sziklai pair it is approximately beta^2, what will happen here?

Comment: What purpose does the 10 u capacitor serve here?

Comment: no, it can't be called a sziklai pair, for that things would have to be matched. Output gain depends on very delicate properties of the transistors which aren't well-speced, exactly like analogsystemsrf explained, so it can't be inferred from the schematic. This whole thing simply seems to be bad, to be honest. Don't just copy some schematics from some website. There's no guarantee anyone has ever tried this, and it certainly doesn't look like they've simulated it.